# duplicate import inside webpack

Tags: plugins, import, webpack

Inside my webpack.config I import a module like this. The configuration is practically the same except for codeSync, port and ui option.  Everything works fine but since I am using Flow.js, ESLint and Standard.js I am getting an error about duplicate code import. Is there a way to make double instances of the same plugin or import this without changing rules of linter. It would be best if I didn't have to make two instance of the same module just for changing one setting or import it twice.

```
import BrowserSyncPlugin from 'browser-sync-webpack-plugin'
import BrowserSyncPluginMobile from 'browser-sync-webpack-plugin'

module.exports = {

...

    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3002,
          ui: {
            port: 3001
          },
          proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          codeSync: false,
          open: false

        }),
        new BrowserSyncPluginMobile({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3004,
          ui: {
            port: 3003
          },
          proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          codeSync: true,
          open: false
        })
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to import the same module twice and your linter is correctly warning you about duplicate imports. They are literally the same module, but assigned to two different names.

Besides the fact that both names refer to the exact same module, the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) creates a new instance of the class (or constructor function). In case you thought that importing a module a second time would create a different instance, which is not the case, but also not necessary at all, because you end up using `new` to create a new instance anyway. The following is equivalent to what you did, without using two different names for the same module.

```
plugins: [
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3002,
    ui: {
      port: 3001
    },
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    codeSync: false,
    open: false
  }),
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3004,
    ui: {
      port: 3003
    },
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    codeSync: true,
    open: false
  })
]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yes, thats what I ended up doing after some thinking. Is there a way to maybe reduce this even further putting it all under same new BrowserSyncPlugin instance?

Comment: I don't think so. The plugin forwards these options to BrowersSync and it doesn't look like you could define multiple ports at once (according to the [docs](https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-port) it must be a number).

Comment: I will just put comments then explaining why we use two of them. Thanks.